# Split string based on second occurrence of delimiter using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split, substring

I have a dynamically formed string like - `part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc` whose length is unknown

In this string I want to get the substring based on second occurrence of "." so that I can get and `part1.abc` `part2.abc` `part3.abc`.

And if the string is like -  `part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc.part4` output must be like `part1.abc` `part2.abc` `part3.abc` `part4`

How to get this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494691/cutting-a-string-at-nth-occurrence-of-a-character

Comment: Even a simple split and then processing it in groups will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this :

```
str="part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc.part4"
temp=str.split('.');
out=[]
for(i=0; i<temp.length;i=i+2)
out.push(temp.slice(i,i+2).join('.'));
//["part1.abc", "part2.abc", "part3.abc", "part4"]
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in my comment, the simplest (and fastest) way is to use a regular expression and match:

```
// ['part1.abc', 'part2.abc', 'part3.abc', 'part4']
'part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc.part4'.match(/[^.]+(\.[^.]+)?/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple function which allows you to specify the number of items to join together and delimiter which you can use to join them.

```
var concatBy = function(list, delimiter, by) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i += by) {
        result.push(list.slice(i, i + by).join(delimiter))
    }
    return result;
}

concatBy('part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc'.split('.'), '.', 2) // returns concatBy('part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc.part4'.split('.'), '.', 2)
concatBy('part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc.part4'.split('.'), '.', 2) // returns ["part1.abc", "part2.abc", "part3.abc", "part4"]
```