# Changing n-th occurrence with regex

Tags: regex

With reference to this SO question: [Cutting a string at nth occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494691/cutting-a-string-at-nth-occurrence-of-a-character)

Have a slightly different question: Can this be done using regex?

```
"aa.bb.cc.dd.ee.xx" => "aa.bb.NN.dd.ee.ff" 
(replacing only 3rd occurrence, all chars are random alphanumeric text )
```

**NOTE:** .split() .slice() .join() is a readable solution, regex seems possible and straightforward (I may be wrong). Eg: replacing the first two "aa." and "bb." with say 'AoA' and 'BoB', seems trivial:-

```
`"aa.bb.cc.dd.ee.xx".replace(/([^\.]*\.){2}/, 'AoA.BoB.')`
```

**Edit:** Since "**.**" means 'matching anything' in regex, please  use "**;**" (semicolon) instead. To make it more difficult, what if we have a string like this:

"ax;;cyz;def;eghi;xyzw" and we wanted to replace 3rd section (eg: cyz)

Comment: NOTE: Personally all 3 answers are acceptable, just that SO only allows 1 acceptable answer *grumble*. **Readers** Do add +1 to the answer(s) that suits you best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex and replace it with `$1Hello$3`. `n-1 => 2`.

```
^((?:[^;]*;){2})([^;]*)(.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oZ8dS3)

Answer (score 3):

To replace the 3rd occurence, you would match:

`^((\w{2}\.){2})\w{2}\.(.*)$`

and replace with:

\1NN.\3

To replace the n-th occurence, you would match:

`^((\w{2}\.){n-1})\w{2}\.(.*)$`

### `Demo`

For your comment:

`^(([^;]*\;){2})[^;]*\;(.*)$`

### `Demo2`

Comment: If I have random chars like `%23;B;ccc;123;efgh;`, then \w{2} match will fail. Nevertheless, good solution for fixed 2 letter char.

Comment: @AlvinK., I have updated my answer for your second case. If it helped, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.

Comment: sshashank124: Demo2 is correct, however @Ulugbek posted his code first, hence I have given him the credits. To note: Demo2 regex uses 'repeated capturing group' since it omits '?:'

Comment: @AlvinK., actually I posted my answer 3 hours ago and posted demo2 2 hours ago. He posted his answer 1 hour ago.

Comment: sshashank124: Demo2 wont parse empty fields like "ax;;cyz;def;eghi;xyzw", but can be fixed by changing '+' to '*' though.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific string instance, you could also use the following.

```
[^.]*(?=(?:\.[^.]*){3}$)
```

Regular expression

```
[^.]*           any character except: '.' (0 or more times)
(?=             look ahead to see if there is:
 (?:            group, but do not capture (3 times):
 \.             '.'
  [^.]*         any character except: '.' (0 or more times)
){3}            end of grouping
 $              before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)               end of look-ahead
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/uD4cL9)

Comment: If you change `{3}` to `{4}`, it matches 'bb'. Hence this is a ideal solution if the delimiters ';' are fixed since it is counting backwards.