# Get value of second last slash

Tags: javascript

```
var path = 'example.com/user/john/red'
path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

I got example.com/user/john

how to get only example.com/user/? means lastSecondIndexOf, but there's no such method.

Comment: This seems to answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494691/cutting-a-string-at-nth-occurrence-of-a-character

Comment: I think you mean you want `example.com/user` as output?

Comment: you can pass an int as second argument to `lastIndexOf()`

Comment: @Ramanlfc that's just the starting position to start looking from.

Comment: you may use like `var path = 'example.com/user/john/red'
var path2 = path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")) var path3 = path2.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf("/"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `.lastIndexOf` takes a second parameter for `fromIndex`, and you could use the last index of the slash in the parameter:

```
path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf("/",path.lastIndexOf("/")-1));
```