# Javascript nth occurance of a string and extract the sub string upto that

Tags: javascript, string

Suppose I have a string like this

```
var str = 'E2*2001/116*0364*31'
```

What I want is to find the 3rd occurrence of * in the string and print up to that from starting.

So result would be `E2*2001/116*0364*`

I have tried something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZKgd/469/).

Corresponding code

```
var str = 'E2*2001/116*0364*31',
delimiter = '*',
start = 0,
var pos=getPosition(str, *, 3);
alert(pos);
tokens = str.substring(start, getPosition(str,*,3)),
result = tokens;


document.body.innerHTML = result;


function getPosition(str, m, i) {
   return str.split(m, i).join(m).length;
}
```

But unable to get the output.

Can anyone please assist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cutting a string at nth occurrence of a character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494691/cutting-a-string-at-nth-occurrence-of-a-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
str.split('*').slice(0,3).join('*') + '*';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'E2*2001/116*0364*31';
console.log(str.match(/^([^*]*\*){3}/)[0]);              // E2*2001/116*0364*
console.log(str.match(/^([^*]*\*){3}/)[0].slice(0, -1)); // E2*2001/116*0364
```

Comment: it does not give me last *

Comment: @Neel, neither your code in the question. If you need last `*` just remove `.slice(0, -1)`.

Comment: @JonathanBrooks, fixed.

Comment: may be you need to mention that this solution requires `regex`

Comment: @Reddy, isn't it clear from regex literal in the code?

Comment: @Qwertiy its only because the OP doesn't have a `regex` tag added to it. Also we cant be sure that beginners can even identify that literal as a `regex'.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var string = 'E2*2001/116*0364*31'.replace(/([^*]+\*){3}/, '');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(string, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```