# How to cut string based on 3rd occurrence of a character?

Tags: javascript

Assuming that I have a string like `$foo$bar$baz $5`

I have tried to split the string to an array by `$', then remove the first and second elements, and then convert the array to a new string. but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do so?

Comment: I want to remove the left part, ie `$foo$bar$`

Comment: I have tried to split the string to an array by `$', then remove the first and second elements, and then convert the array to a new string.  but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cutting a string at nth occurrence of a character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494691/cutting-a-string-at-nth-occurrence-of-a-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the first two occurences of `$` and some text with an empty string.

> ```
> ^(\$[^$]+){2}\$    regular expression
> ^                  start of the string
>   \$               search for $ literally
>     [^$]           search for any character but not $
>         +          quantifier one or more
>  (       )         group
>           {2}      quantifier for exactly two times
>  (       ){2}      get the group only two times
>              \$    get the third $
> ```

```js
var string = '$foo$bar$baz $5',
    result = string.replace(/^(\$[^$]+){2}\$/, '');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You beat me to it :D 2 sec difference.

Comment: Nice one! can you add some explanation about how the magic work?

Comment: Sorry I did not notice this: the result should be `baz $5` not `$baz $5`. Can you still do that in a single regexp function?

Comment: how would this be rewritten to return from the start of the string to the nth occurrence instead of returning from the nth occurrence to the end?

Comment: @Benjamin, take `match` and only the first index of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Review it:-

```
var str = '$foo$bar$baz $5',
delimiter = '$',
start = 3,
tokens = str.split(delimiter).slice(start),
result = tokens.join(delimiter);
console.log(result); //baz $5
```