# Regex expression to cut string at nth occurrence of character and return first part of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have found the answer for a case which returns the second part of the string, eg:

`"qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x".replace(/([^\_]*\_){**nth**}/, '');` - where is nth is the amount of occurrence to remove.

If **nth**=3, the above will return “xcv_xcv_x”

Details in this StackOverflow post: [Cutting a string at nth occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494691/cutting-a-string-at-nth-occurrence-of-a-character)

How to change the above regular expression to return the first part instead (ie. “qwe_fs_xczv”)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to look from the start (`^`) of the string, for three sequences of characters  without underscore, that might start with an underscore ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LTW5Cs/1)):

```js
const result = "qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x".match(/^(?:_?[^_]+){3}/);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [end anchor(`$`)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to assert ending position.

```
"qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x".replace(/(_[^_]*){nth}$/, ''); 
//            --------------------^-----------^--- here
```

```js
console.log(
  "qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x".replace(/(_[^_]*){3}$/, '')
)
```

---

**UPDATE :** In order to get the first n segments you need to use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with slight variation in the regex.

```
"qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x".match(/(?:(?:^|_)[^_]*){3}/)[0]
```

```js
console.log(
  "qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x".match(/(?:(?:^|_)[^_]*){3}/)[0]
)
```

In the above regex `(?:^|_)` helps to assert the start position or matching the leading `_`.
[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/K5dura/2).

---

Another alternative for the regex would be, `/^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){n-1}/`. Final regex would be like:

```
/^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){2}/
```

```js
console.log(
  "qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x".match(/^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*){2}/)[0]
)
```

Comment: Almost there :-) I like the simplicity of your answer but this one cuts from the end. My string has unknown number of segments. How to change it to return only the first 3 segments from the left?

Comment: It works, thanks. I went with Ori Drori answer since it's the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `replace`, then capture up to right before the third `_` and replace with that group:

```js
const re = /^(([^_]*_){2}[^_]*(?=_)).*$/;
console.log("qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x".replace(re, '$1'));
console.log("qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x_x_x".replace(re, '$1'));
```

But it would be nicer to use `match` to match the desired substring directly:

```js
const re = /^([^_]*_){2}[^_]*(?=_)/;
console.log("qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x".match(re)[0])
console.log("qwe_fs_xczv_xcv_xcv_x_x_x".match(re)[0])
```