# use str.split() on every second occurrence of our delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a series of varying strings which I need to turn into arrays on every second occurrence of `\n`, for simplicity please consider the next example:

```
const str = 'banana\napple\nmango\n3.5'

//I have tried and failed with:

const arr = str.split(/(^\n)+\n(^\n)+/)

// Result should be:
// const arr = ['banana\napple', 'mango\n3.5']
```

Do I have to use a loop here or what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cutting a string at nth occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494691/cutting-a-string-at-nth-occurrence-of-a-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take `match` instead of `split` by taking some non breaking character, a breaking character and other non breking character.

```js
const
    string = 'banana\napple\nmango\n3.5',
    result = string.match(/[^\n]+\n[^\n]+/g);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Damn this is an ugly approach:

```js
 
let t1 = performance.now();

const result = 'banana\napple\nmango\n3.5'
    .split('\n')
    .map((str, i, arr) => (i % 2) === 0 ? str + '\n' + arr[i+1] : null )
    .filter((str) => str !== null);
    
let t2 = performance.now();
console.log(result, t2-t1 + 'μs');
```